# How to alter session in oracle to the value of $ORACLE_SID

Tags: oracle, schema

I have lot of databases where schema name is the same as $ORACLE_SID. I would like when i log in to sqlplus something like:

```
alter session set current_schema=$ORACLE_SID
```

is executed. Everything what I've tried didn't work.

Comment: This sounds like a strange setup. Why are you using one instance per user/schema? And why don't you simply log in with that user? Then you don't need the `alter session` in the first place?

Comment: its strange, but actually pretty normal in some corporation. He may not have the password for the user and need to run scripts under that user (aka not referencing the owner in the objects)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put such a code into:

- login.sql (locally in where you executed sqlplus)
- or glogin.sql ($ORACLE_HOME\sqlplus\admin)

> ```
> declare
>   l_gln varchar2(30);
> begin
>   select instance_name into l_gln from v$instance;
>   execute immediate 'alter session set current_schema = ' || l_gln; 
> end;
> /
> ```